# Duplicate key value violates unique constraint on database initializzation

Tags: python, django, postgresql, initialization, django-taggit

I have a model for a blog where I want to set the `finished` field equals `True` if the other fields are not empty. I populate the database (Postgres) using a script but somethings is not working on initializzation (database is empty, but after migration, so the tables exist).

my `models.py`:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.title_it!='' and self.title_en!='' and self.text_it!='' and self.text_en!='' and self.tags!='':
            self.finished=True
            super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

My script `init.py`:

```
def add_post(author, title_it, title_en, text_it, text_en, created_date, 
    published_date, tags, views):
    p = Post.objects.get_or_create(author=author, title_it=title_it, 
        title_en=title_en, text_it=text_it, text_en=text_en, 
        created_date=created_date, published_date=published_date, 
        views=views)[0]
    for t in tags:
        p.tags.add(t)
    p.save()
    return p
```

and the error when I run the script:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "blog_post_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
```

Here the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\progetti\Envs\possedimenti\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.p
y", line 487, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**lookup), False
  File "D:\progetti\Envs\possedimenti\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.p
y", line 403, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
blog.models.DoesNotExist: Post matching query does not exist.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\progetti\Envs\possedimenti\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils
.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.IntegrityError: ERRORE:  un valore chiave duplicato viola il vincolo un
ivoco "blog_post_pkey"
DETAIL:  La chiave (id)=(1) esiste già.


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "init_poss.py", line 8374, in <module>
    populate()
  File "init_poss.py", line 7311, in populate
    ['Servizio'], 1) #tzinfo=<UTC>
  File "init_poss.py", line 8323, in add_post
    views=views)[0]
  File "D:\progetti\Envs\possedimenti\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager
.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\progetti\Envs\possedimenti\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.p
y", line 489, in get_or_create
    return self._create_object_from_params(lookup, params)
  File "D:\progetti\Envs\possedimenti\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.p
y", line 528, in _create_object_from_params
    raise e
  File "D:\progetti\Envs\possedimenti\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.p
y", line 521, in _create_object_from_params
    obj = self.create(**params)
  File "D:\progetti\Envs\possedimenti\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.p
y", line 417, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "D:\progetti\possedimenti\sitopossedimenti\blog\models.py", line 58, in s
ave
    super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\progetti\Envs\possedimenti\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py
", line 729, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "D:\progetti\Envs\possedimenti\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py
", line 759, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, upda
te_fields)
  File "D:\progetti\Envs\possedimenti\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py
", line 842, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "D:\progetti\Envs\possedimenti\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py
", line 880, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "D:\progetti\Envs\possedimenti\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager
.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\progetti\Envs\possedimenti\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.p
y", line 1125, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "D:\progetti\Envs\possedimenti\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\com
piler.py", line 1283, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\progetti\Envs\possedimenti\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils
.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\progetti\Envs\possedimenti\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils
.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._e
xecute)
  File "D:\progetti\Envs\possedimenti\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils
.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "D:\progetti\Envs\possedimenti\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils
.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\progetti\Envs\possedimenti\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", lin
e 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "D:\progetti\Envs\possedimenti\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils
.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: ERRORE:  un valore chiave duplicato viola il vin
colo univoco "blog_post_pkey"
DETAIL:  La chiave (id)=(1) esiste già.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here :

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.title_it!='' and self.title_en!='' and self.text_it!='' and self.text_en!='' and self.tags!='':
        self.finished=True
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

You are calling `super().save()` a second time with the same kwarg. since the `force_insert` arg is set to `True` as you can see from the traceback:

```
File "D:\progetti\Envs\possedimenti\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 521, in _create_object_from_params
    obj = self.create(**params)
File "D:\progetti\Envs\possedimenti\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 417, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
```

you end up asking the ORM to create a second record, and since by that time the pk has been set (by the first `super.save()` call), you indeed get a unique constraint violation.

You could try and start messing with kwargs but that's actually a bad idea (better leave those flags to the ORM) - the simple solution is to make sure you call `super.save()` only once:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # non-empty strings have a true value
    # so no need to explicitely test against
    # the empty string.
    # Note that this test will probably not
    # behave how you expect with strings containing
    # only space characters but that was your original
    # code behaviour too so I left this alone.
    self.finished = (
      self.title_it and self.title_en 
      and self.text_it and self.text_en 
      and self.tags
      )
    super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Edit: since `self.tags` is actually a related field (from the `taggit` app) you can't test `self.tags` unconditionnally as you need the instance to have been saved in db before you can access any related object. The solution here is to test against `self.pk` first and only test the other fields if relevant:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.pk:
        self.finished = (
          self.title_it and self.title_en 
          and self.text_it and self.text_en 
          # unless `taggit` does some weird things
          # wrt/ tags storage, this should be the 
          # right test
          and self.tags.exists()
          )
    else:
        # no pk so no flags so it can not be finished
        self.finished = False

    # and call `super.save()` whatever the case
    super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. How can I do? If I don't call the first super.save() it gives an error because 'Post objects need to have a primary key value before you can access their tags'. For the tags I'using taggit

Comment: AOK - but then your test is probably wrong - you should not be comparing `self.tags` to the empty string.